# Two AC inputs - one DC motor

Tags: motor, relay, dc, motor-controller

First of all, I'm a total novice.

My parents have an old electric curtain pulley system from probably the 70's. It's run by a universal motor connected to a 3-position switch.
The switch positions are OFF - LEFT - RIGHT.
3 wires run from the switch to the motor (common black, plus a blue and a brown from the switch positions).

By inspecting the wiring, it looks like it just runs the universal motor forwards or reverse by engaging only one of the two stator coils (the blue wire runs to one stator coil and the brown wire runs to the other one). Both stator coils share the same black wire (I'm assuming it's the live wire - it runs through an old capacitor/filter thing first and in series with the rotor).

I want to toss the awful, ancient, noisy spark-frenzy fire hazard of a motor and replace it with a quiet DC motor. The old motor is rated 200/90W whatever that means. I would like to keep the switch though, so my question is: How do I control the direction of a DC motor using AC wires - one live wire and two neutrals?

Many thanks in advance :-)

edit: It's actually only 2 wires coming from the switch to the motor. The common live wire is just from the wall.

Here's the current schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fC880B.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here's an attempt at a solution. It's probably pretty naive. And if someone could tell me if a relay can be controlled with an AC signal or not, that would be great.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRWFDN.png)</sup>

Somebody said relays couldn't be wired in series with the transformer, so here's another attempt using two relays: Please tell me if it would work.

edited: cleaned it up a little

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNFIFL.png)</sup>

Comment: Are you looking to keep just the switch and the wires to the motor, or also the mains connection into the switch?

Comment: I haven't really considered that as an option actually. I suppose there would be no harm in opening up the switch panel and make changes there too.

Comment: You can use the schematic editor to shown the current circuit and what you think might work. A current wiring diagram would also help.

Comment: Cool you guys have a schematic editor embedded :D I just drew the current system. It's really simple. I hope it makes sense.
I really don't know much about circuits and motors, so I can't even guess to a solution.

Comment: I would suggest getting somebody with experiences with the mains to either tutor or help you. There are many ways of becoming crispy and this has many paths.

Comment: Many thanks for the concern and I really do appreciate it. I feel like this project falls within my comfort zone though.

Comment: I made an attempt at a solution myself. It's in the OP. Please tell me if it's normal to control a relay with an AC signal or not.

Comment: Is it legal for you to work on house mains? If not, call an electrician so you are not responsible if the installation is hazardous, like someone gets an electric shock or it starts a fire. Unless you have good insurance that covers those. There are relays with DC coils and AC coils, and you would not connect the coil in series with a transformer.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the legal considerations. But I am prepared for the risk and it's all good. I appreciate the tip though!

Comment: By looking at your schematic it is clear you do not have a nessessary knowledge to do it yourself. DC motors have many types and can be controlled differently. Just get some professional help.

Comment: With respect to everybody's profession and hard-earned knowledge, I'm not here to get anyone's blessing for the project. I'm only here to learn and to make it work :-)

Comment: _”The old motor is rated 200/90W whatever that means.”_ How many wires coming out of it? Could be two separate windings, high and low speed.

Comment: I actually disassembled it and there are six wires in total. Two for each of the stator coils and two for the rotor brushes. The rotor is connected in series with the stator coils externally through an old capacitor/filter thing. It looks to me like only one of the two stator coils are engaged at any time depending on the switch position.
Anyway, the description of the old motor isn't actually all that relevant, since I'm just trying to replace it with a DC motor.

Comment: There are relays that will operate on various AC voltages, including mains voltage.

Comment: What is the reason that you would not want to connect a relay in series with a transformer?

Comment: I made another attempt at a solution. This time the relay(s) are in parallel with the transformer. Please tell me if it would work.

Comment: That looks like it might work. I suppose the advantage is that it disconnects the DC power supply when not running the motor.

Answer (score 1):

The safest way to proceed would be to avoid all connection to the AC mains, except for a DC power supply with about 200 VA capacity (12VDC 16A or 24 VDC 8A). As long as the PSU is properly current limited and fused, you will eliminate most risk of electric shock and fire. Then find a suitable DC motor, which could be a 12V automotive window motor, and build a circuit like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fC1pM7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>